# -uan pinyin pronunciation

Tags: mandarin, pronunciation, pinyin

It seems to me that in Mandarin, two different vowel sounds are used for words whose pinyin ends with -uan.

In some words, like 全 (quán) and 元 (yuán), the vowel sounds like "oo-en" (the nucleus/coda are "ɛn" in IPA, rhymes with English "hen").

In other words, like 換/换 (huàn) and 亂/乱 (luàn), the vowel sounds like "oo-an" (the nucleus/coda are "an" in IPA, rhymes with Mandarin "安").

Does this difference really exist, or an I imagining it? If there is a distinction, what's the rule for which pronunciation to use? It seems related to the tone and the initial consonant, but I'm not sure there is a definite pattern.

Comment: It's also possible that this is an accent difference and I've just internalized different speakers' pronunciations of these words (c.f. https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/17266/mandarin-pronunciation-for-hen-and-yuan).

Comment: It's better to look at *u* as part of *yu-* which is the same as *ü-*. Pīnyīn is actually very consistent when you [learn its handful of abbreviations and orthography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinyin#Orthographic_rules).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several cases in Mandarin of multiple sounds sharing the same symbols in Pinyin, such as -uan as you've noticed, as well as -i which has multiple sounds associated with it. In the case of -uan, this final behaves differently when prefaced with the initials y-, j-, q-, and x-. As a general rule, -u, -ue, -uan, and -un behave differently when prefaced with those 4 initials and you'll see them separated  out on any pinyin chart:

[image]

The u in these cases is actually a ü which does not exist in English and is something I struggle with myself so I'll just redirect you [here](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/pronunciation/The_%22%C3%BC%22_vowel).

Answer (score 2):

When `ü` is used in zero initial syllables, use `yu` instead:

- ü → yu (鱼)
- üe → yue (月)
- üan → yuan (元)
- ün → yun (云)

You should read these `yu` as `ü`.

---

When `ü` is used with `j`, `q`, `x`, use `u` instead:

- ü → ju (巨), qu (去), xu (许)
- üe → jue (绝), que (却), xue (学)
- üan → juan (卷), quan (全), xuan (选)
- ün → jun (军), qun (群), xun (寻)

You should read these `u` as `ü`.

---

In all other cases, use `ü` as is:

- nü (女), lü (绿), nüe (疟), lüe (略)

---

In your example, `u` in `huan`, `luan` are different from `u` in `quan`, `juan`. First ones read as `u`, the second ones read as `ü` actually. And `yuan` reads as `üan`.